# C++ stl map

Tags: stl, map, c++

Работает:(Все в одном файле ConsoleApplication4.cpp)

```
    #include <string>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;

    map < int, string > GetVar(string str, string sep)
    {
        map<int, string >  result;
        result[0] = str;
        return result;
    }

int main()
{
    string str;
    map<int, string >  var;
    var = GetVar("s1 s2 s3 s4 s5", "");

    for(map<int, string >::iterator it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).second << "\n";
    }
    cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

Не работает:

ConsoleApplication4.cpp:

```
#include "helpers.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    map<int, string >  var;
    var = GetVar("s1 s2 s3 s4 s5", "");

    for(map<int, string >::iterator it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).second << "\n";
    }
    cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

helpers.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map < int, string > GetVar(string str, string sep)
{
    map<int, string >  result;
    result[0] = str;
    return result;
}
```

Функция должна вернуть ассоциативный.
В чем ошибка:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>helpers.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > __cdecl GetVar(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?GetVar@@YA?AV?$map@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@H@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@0@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication4.obj
1>C:\Users\Вадим\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Release\ConsoleApplication4.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: У вас ошибка линковщика, а не компилятора. Вы два раза определяете GetVars, естественно оно у Вас не линкуется.

Comment: У вас GetVars сначала компилируется в helpers.cpp, а потом в ConsoleApplication4.cpp.

Comment: И вообще, кто вам подсказал что можно инклудить .cpp файлы?

Comment: Честно, я ни кого и не спрашивал :) Пока я еще чайник в c++, не подскажете как корректно инклудить? Я планировал сделать класс helpers, это функция была первой в этом классе, но начала вылазить ошибка. Как я понял компилтор сначала компилит из проекта и потом опять компилит уже из инклуда.

Comment: @avengerweb: Вы плаваете в совершенно базовых вещах. А какой учебник по C++ вы читали? Если никакой, то совет очевиден.

Comment: Пока нет особо времени читать литературу, по тихому гуглю и ищу нужный мне функционал. Увы нет такого учебники, в котором было бы только, то что "нужно", куча мешуры, это не для меня.

Comment: @avengerweb, конечно, никому не охота читать по 800 страниц "базы" по С++, потом ещё полировать её всякими "50 дополнительными советами по улучшению кода", но тут нужно понимать, что потом ваш код предстоит кому-то сопровождать и важно писать его не "с мира по нитке", а вникая во все тонкости.

Comment: @avengerweb: Вы хотите научиться программировать? Тогда заставьте себя прочитать _и понять_ эти самые 800 страниц, мы же все так сделали. Если вы хотите не научиться, а скопипастить кусок, вряд ли многие захотят вам помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы функция GetVar находилась в другом файле, то есть вариант просто обернуть её в класс и вызывать уже в main как функцию этого класса:

helpers.h

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Helpers
{
public:
    Helpers() {}
    ~Helpers() {}

public:
    map<int, string> GetVar(string str, string sep)
    {
        map<int, string >  result;
        result[0] = str;
        return result;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string str;
    map<int, string >  var;
    Helpers obj;

    var = obj.GetVar("s1 s2 s3 s4 s5", "");

    for(map<int, string >::iterator it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << (*it).second << "\n";
    }
    cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

Да, описание класса должно находиться в файле .h (header), а реализация в .cpp. В данном случае, мы всё оставляем в .h для экономии места, т. к. у нас мало кода.
Затем, если вы не используете каким-то образом библиотеку, то и не стоит включать её заголовочный файл, как в случае с #include <iostream> в вашем helpers.cpp
По неймспейсам - если вы указали, что используете неймспейс std в одном файле и включаете его в другой, то не нужно указывать это снова в этом файле - достаточно одного раза + если вы уже указали факт использования того или иного пространства имён, то не нужно писать конструкции вида std::cout, компилятор сам поймёт, откуда взять cout.
А ещё не понятно, для чего нужен аргумент string sep в GetVar, если он не используется, но возможно он вами зарезервирован "на будущее". 
Вот, наверное что-то упустил)

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема была и правда в include. Компилятор VS, сначало компилил файл, как из проекта, а потом компили из инклуда.